# programmatically remove background picture from image view in android

Tags: android-layout

I have set a background image in inmage view in my android application. Now I want to remove this background picture programmatically. How to do this?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
imgView.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

Comment: Perfect Solution.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
imgView.setImageBitmap(null);
```

Comment: This is working and should be the accepted answer. Though the result is the same as filling the ImageView with transparent color, just a guess, but chances are that this here costs less.

Comment: This is working when you have set ex. bitmap as background in the imgView something like: `imgView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap)` in your code, but if you have `imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mybackground);` then the accepted answer will do the job

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer removes the image resource of the image view ,if you want to remove the background resource then do

```
imageView.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

also adding in some explanation, this actually doesnot remove the background resource completely,it will just replace the existing background resource with a transparent color ,so it appears like the background is removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(null)
```

This will remove the image associated with your `imageView`. Similarly, if you want to add another image, you can use:

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(_your_drawable_object_).
```

As the name suggests, this takes a drawable object not an int.