# Animate ImageView without background

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview

I am trying to animate an ImageView and things are working well however I have one slight problem - when the animation is ongoing I can see a white background in which the image slides in. I don't want to see this white background.

[image]

[image]

As you can see on image1 and 2 there is this white background in which the batman logo slides in. I don't want to see this white background.

EDIT1:

animation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fillBefore="true"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fromYDelta="-100%p"
    android:toYDelta="0"
    />
</set>
```

layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/main_CV_spidie_top"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/main_IV_spidey_top"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="20sp"
        android:src="@drawable/batman_logo" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/main_CV_spidey_left"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/main_IV_spidey_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="20sp"
        android:src="@drawable/batman_logo" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please post relevant codes. It is impossible to understand where the problem is. Is your image itself has a transparent bg ?

Answer (score 1):

try this to set a transparent background in your `imageview` in `XML` code:

```
android:background="@null"
```

also check [programatically remove background picture from image view in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482129/programatically-remove-background-picture-from-image-view-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Try this property to your Image View

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/main_IV_spidey_top"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:elevation="20sp"
    android:src="@drawable/batman_logo" />
```